# Django admin panel Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using daterangefilter to filter result according to dates but my datepicker is not working.Its showing datepicker icon but not working.

I tried to reinstall daterangefilter as well as django-suite(seen somewhere while searching for the solution) to identify the problem but it is in same state.

```
list_filter = ['company', 'status', 'published', 'dont_publish',('created_at', DateRangeFilter)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing static files, as stated in the [`django-daterangefilter`](https://pypi.org/project/django-daterangefilter/) package description:

> Application uses static files so do not forget to issue `collectstatic`
>   management command in production environment.